# image segmentation can't generate result

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, pytorch, deconvolution

Building an Encoder-Decoder sequence for image segmentation,That’s to say,I use black background and white foreground to train the whole network.and in test process, it generate nothing but black[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfUbY.jpg)
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsaun.jpg)

I check the softmax output, find that it does treat the background pixel to 0 channel, so argmax op generate 0 at this pixel.But foreground pixel’s softmax output is even. just(0.5,0.5),so it can’t distinguish,so the argmax chose the natural order 0 to present the class,and generate 0.
So when I use argmax it generate all black image, while the argmin to genrate 
 reverse result,which means it distinguish the background,but at these even pixels,the network fails.[image]
I conjecture that I use a different deconv process.https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/ that’s which inspires me. cause I used to use deconv,but it generate checkerboard artifacts inside the white area.[image]so I follow the blog to use upsampling layer and a size-keeping conv operation to replace the deconv layer.But it fails,too.WHERE to modify?I really confused, and, a bit upset.

the two problem [My Image segmentation result map contains black lattice in in the white patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145527/my-image-segmentation-result-map-contains-black-lattice-in-in-the-white-patch,it) also launched by myself, but it's different.they use different model to generate different result,the former is about deconv layer ,the latter is about checkerboard atrifact and its solution:upsampling,which still fails on my network,cause it produce only black pixels, and unable to categorize white area pixels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Image segmentation result map contains black lattice in in the white patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145527/my-image-segmentation-result-map-contains-black-lattice-in-in-the-white-patch)